# How to get the second position of the folder name from path using regex shell script

Tags: shell

Input:

path="/var/talend/nat/cdc"

Expected Output: `nat`

I have tried the below solution but it giving last folder name "cdc"

```
path1=${path##*/}
```

Comment: `path1="${path%/*}"; path1="${path1##*/}"` (trim from the right -- then trim from the left)

Comment: you can also use `basename "$(dirname "$path")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)} '
```

Demo:

```
$echo $path
/var/talend/nat/cdc
$echo $path  |  awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)} '
nat
$
```

NF -- Number of fields